# How can GeoJson polygons be colored programmatically using OpenLayers 6?

Tags: javascript, style, openlayers

In my GeoJSON file, there is an attribute for each polygon. I am trying to update the fillcolor of the polygon base on the value of an attribute in the GeoJSON file. I have a function `getColor()` that returns a color, based on the input value.

There is already similar solution, but that was in 2012.

Can you help me?

> `Error("${getColor(ID)}"): Unexpected template string expression. (no-template-curly-in-string)`

```
var styles = [
  new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: "blue",
      width: 3
    }),
    fill: new Fill({
      color: "${getColor(ID)}"
    })
  },
  {
    context: 
    {

      getColor : function (feature) {
        return feature.attributes.ID > 950 ? '#800026' :
        feature.attributes.ID > 750 ? '#BD0026' :
        feature.attributes.ID > 500 ? '#E31A1C' :
        feature.attributes.ID > 250 ? '#FC4E2A' :
        feature.attributes.ID > 150 ? '#FD8D3C' :
        feature.attributes.ID > 50  ? '#FEB24C' :
        feature.attributes.ID > 10  ? '#FED976' :
        '#FFEDA0' ;
      }
    } 
  })
];
```

Comment: Please link to the "similar solution" to keep things connected.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay enough attention. I deleted my post. What you are looking for is a [`StyleFunction`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Style.html#~StyleFunction) that takes the feature as input and returns the correct `Style`.

Comment: The use of those is implemented here: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/earthquake-clusters.html Please answer your own question if you find a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You should style the layer with a style function

```
var style = new Style({
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: 'blue',
    width: 3
  }),
  fill: new Fill()
});

var styleFunction = function (feature) {
  var id = feature.getId();
  var color = 
    id > 950 ? '#800026' :
    id > 750 ? '#BD0026' :
    id > 500 ? '#E31A1C' :
    id > 250 ? '#FC4E2A' :
    id > 150 ? '#FD8D3C' :
    id > 50  ? '#FEB24C' :
    id > 10  ? '#FED976' :
               '#FFEDA0' ;
  style.getFill().setColor(color);
  return style;
};
```

Example here https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-esri-0vjwn

Feature do not have an `attribute` property.  The feature id is accessed using `getId()` and other attributes using `get('attribute-name')`

Comment: how do I correctly take the "ID" values from a json file? here is my json

Comment: { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": 2, "begin": 11, "end": 20 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 46.00576, 58.08009 ], [ 46.00576, 58.11442 ], [ 45.85899, 58.1373 ], [ 45.56547, 58.12586 ], [ 45.51655, 58.08009 ], [ 45.51655, 58.04577 ], [ 45.76115, 58.02288 ], [ 45.81007, 58.02288 ], [ 45.85899, 58.03432 ], [ 46.00576, 58.02288 ], [ 46.00576, 58.08009 ] ] ] ] } },

Comment: That is in the properties collection so is accessed in an OpenLayers feature using `.get('ID')`

Comment: thank you very much, friend. You are the best! everything works!